# Regex that identifies sections in COBOL

Tags: regex, cobol, regex-lookarounds, adobe-brackets

I'm customising an outline plugin for Brackets that uses regex to identify the outline of the currently opened file.

Using regex101.com I've created the following regex (uses lookarounds to determine that the line starts with seven spaces and ends with ' SECTION.'):

```
(?<=^       )([A-Za-z\-0-9]*)(?= SECTION\.[ ]*$)
```

According to regex101.com it is okay, however when validated via jshint/jslint it states that it's invalid. When I test it, it doesn't work (I suspect that JSHint/JSLint is correct).

The following is an example of some cobol code where I wish to get 2000-GET-EXPECTED-BY-DATE and 2020-GET-DUE-DATE.

```
          ...
      2000-GET-EXPECTED-BY-DATE SECTION.
          MOVE '2' TO W10-OPTION.

          ...

          ELSE                                                     
              MOVE 'Y' TO W10-NO-ERRORS                         
          END-IF.                                                  

      2017-EXIT.                                                   
          EXIT.                                                   
     /
      2020-GET-DUE-DATE SECTION.
      2020.

          MOVE 'N' TO W10-USER-INPUT-DUE-DATE-SW.
          MOVE '1' TO W10-OPTION.
          ...
```

So my questions are:

- Is the regex is valid?
- If invalid, then what have I done wrong?
- How should I write the regex to find the name of each section?

Comment: What if the 1st 6 characters hold line numbers or version info ???. Many Cobol compilers will accept anything in the first 6 characters ???

Comment: In addition, a SECTION *can* be follwed by a number (extremely unlikely to be seen these days) and the full-stop/period does not need to immediately follow it. The SECTION does not have to be on the same line as the procedure-name, and neither does the full-stop/period which terminates it. If you want something general, then you've got that and more to cover. If something specific for your systems then you have a chance.

Comment: @BruceMartin I'm using it for known code that will only ever have spaces before the section name.

Comment: @BillWoodger This is specific to our legacy code, we don't have the scenarios that you describe.

Comment: +1 for mixing regex and Cobol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me to find the lines with "SECTION":

```
^[ ]{7}(.*)[ ]SECTION\.$
```

**DEMO:** http://regex101.com/r/zC1xY6/2

If you only want the section names: `^[ ]{7}\d+\-(.*)[ ]SECTION\.$`

Comment: Thank you Jenny, that is perfect for what I was trying to do (I'll be using the one that includes the whole name. I'll have to research the options you used, I thought I would need to use look arounds. Any insight into why mine was failing?

Comment: If there is a blank line before the section line then it reports the match with a leading space. If the line before the section has spaces then it increased the number of leading spaces by the number of spaces. It appears to be matching from the end of the previous non blank line to the first non blank character after the 7th position. Please see: http://regex101.com/r/hV8tY7/2

Comment: It is because \s matches spaces, tabs and line breaks too. I have edited the answer to use [ ] to identify spaces.

Comment: Thank you Jenny, the first one is now working. However the second one only works if the previous line has a value, if there is a blank line then it doesn't pick it up.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out that what I had used actually works, with two comments:

- Need to add the global and multiline modifier when used via regex101.com,
- It performs very slowly, such that regex101.com times out on a large program.

However I discovered (via experimentation on regex101.com) that if I change it to

```
^       (.*)(?= SECTION\.[ ]*$)
```

Then it works with no timeout issues. It seems that if I use `^[ ]{7}` as the prefix or I use `([A-Za-z0-9-]*)` as the capturing group to match the name then it is very slow.

The main issue appears to be the performance of `(.*)` when compared to `([A-Za-z0-9-]*)`, the later is a lot slower.

I can use the look behind on regex101.com: `(?<=^       )(.*)(?= SECTION\.[ ]*$)`, however it is getting an error with JSLint/JSHint. So I'll avoid using it.

I've tested the first one `^       (.*)(?= SECTION\.[ ]*$)` in a fork of the brackets outline program and it works! :-)

Comment: Nice thinking there. A speed test with large amount of data is always reasonable to improve your regex. (.*) is of course faster, because it does not have to match characters. It simply takes any of them.

Comment: Thanks @JennyO'Reilly, your quite correct, the character matching was the problem. I've accepted your answer because it was first, only my newbieness with regex made me not realise about \s :-) Based on a very large program, there doesn't appear to be much different in performance when using a lookahead or not.